# Last trading day of each month from a given list using python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, numpy-slicing

date = ['2010-01-11' '2010-01-12' '2010-01-13' '2010-01-14' '2010-01-15'
'2010-01-16' '2010-01-17' '2010-01-18' '2010-01-19' '2010-01-20'
'2010-01-21' '2010-01-22' '2010-01-23' '2010-01-24' '2010-01-25'
'2010-01-26' '2010-01-27' '2010-01-28' '2010-01-29' '2010-01-30'
'2010-01-31' '2010-02-01' '2010-02-02' '2010-02-03' '2010-02-04'
'2010-02-05' '2010-02-06' '2010-02-07' '2010-02-08' '2010-02-09'
'2010-02-10' '2010-02-11' '2010-02-12' '2010-02-13' '2010-02-14'
'2010-02-15' '2010-02-16' '2010-02-17' '2010-02-18' '2010-02-19'
'2010-02-20' '2010-02-21' '2010-02-22' '2010-02-23' '2010-02-24'
'2010-02-25' '2010-02-26' '2010-02-27' '2010-02-28' '2010-03-01'
'2010-03-02' '2010-03-03' '2010-03-04' '2010-03-05' '2010-03-06'
'2010-03-07' '2010-03-08' '2010-03-09' '2010-03-10' '2010-03-11'
'2010-03-12' '2010-03-13' '2010-03-14' '2010-03-15' '2010-03-16'
'2010-03-17' '2010-03-18' '2010-03-19' '2010-03-20' '2010-03-21'
'2010-03-22' '2010-03-23' '2010-03-24' '2010-03-25' '2010-03-26'
'2010-03-27' '2010-03-28' '2010-03-29' '2010-03-30' '2010-03-31'
'2010-04-01' '2010-04-02' '2010-04-03' '2010-04-04' '2010-04-05'
'2010-04-06' '2010-04-07' '2010-04-08' '2010-04-09' '2010-04-10'
'2010-04-11' '2010-04-12' '2010-04-13' '2010-04-14' '2010-04-15'
'2010-04-16' '2010-04-17' '2010-04-18' '2010-04-19' '2010-04-20'
'2010-04-21' '2010-04-22' '2010-04-23' '2010-04-24' '2010-04-25'
'2010-04-26' '2010-04-27' '2010-04-28' '2010-04-29' '2010-04-30'
'2010-05-01' '2010-05-02' '2010-05-03' '2010-05-04' '2010-05-05'
'2010-05-06' '2010-05-07' '2010-05-08' '2010-05-09' '2010-05-10'
'2010-05-11' '2010-05-12' '2010-05-13' '2010-05-14' '2010-05-15'
'2010-05-16' '2010-05-17' '2010-05-18' '2010-05-19' '2010-05-20'
'2010-05-21' '2010-05-22' '2010-05-23' '2010-05-24' '2010-05-25'
'2010-05-26' '2010-05-27' '2010-05-28' '2010-05-29' '2010-05-30'
'2010-05-31' '2010-06-01' '2010-06-02' '2010-06-03' '2010-06-04'
'2010-06-05' '2010-06-06' '2010-06-07' '2010-06-08' '2010-06-09'
'2010-06-10' '2010-06-11' '2010-06-12' '2010-06-13' '2010-06-14'
'2010-06-15' '2010-06-16' '2010-06-17' '2010-06-18' '2010-06-19'
'2010-06-20' '2010-06-21' '2010-06-22' '2010-06-23' '2010-06-24'
'2010-06-25' '2010-06-26' '2010-06-27' '2010-06-28' '2010-06-29'
'2010-06-30']

cant seem to figure out the coding to extract the last day of each month in the above list. please note that the last day of each month in the above list does not necessary equivalent to the last day of each calender month.

Expected output:
['2010-01-29', '2010-02-26', '2010-03-31', '2010-04-30', '2010-05-28', '2010-06-30']

saw some solution as follows but it does not return to an valid outcome:
date = date - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
previous_month = '01'
last_trading_days = []

for index, day in enumerate(date):
    # Extract month from date
    month = day[5:7]
    
    # If this is the first day of the new month, append the day that came before it
    if month != previous_month:
        previous_month = month
        last_trading_days.append(date[index - 1])
    
    # Also append the last day
    if index == len(date) - 1:
        last_trading_days.append(day)
        
print(last_trading_days)
```

This is if you know the first month will be January, otherwise you can use `previous_month = date[0][5:7]` to start on the month of the first date in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Download stock data for each last trading day of the month till date:

```py
df = yf.download(symbol,period='max') 
df = df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')).tail(1)
```